# Slider hooked up to a Web Audio API gain node is popping and clicking when I drag it. No smooth ramp in volume as I drag

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web-audio-api

A gain node is hooked up to a UI slider via an HTML input type 'range'. Got it to successfully change the volume as I drag, but no matter how I set the step size, I hear noise when I drag on the slider.

the HTML looks like this:

```
   <input id="slider6Volume" type="range" min="0.0008" max="1.0008" step="0.0001" value="0.0008" oninput="changeGain(this.value)"/>
```

The .js is like this:

```
function changeGain(newValue) {

document.getElementById('slider6Volume').addEventListener('input', function() {

gainNode6.gain.setValueAtTime(newValue, audioCtx.currentTime);  
console.log ("Channel 6: ", this.value);

}, "false");
```

I started with float values that weren't nearly so tiny, but this resulted in audible stairstepping between gain values. It sounds like it's getting conflicting gain updates, but the console dump I hooked up looks ok. Float values in a steady uninterrupted ordered stream. What am I missing?

Comment: A more complete example would certainly be helpful.  Also, setValueAtTime(v, context.currentTime) may be slightly off because the currentTime is in the audio thread, not the main thread, so context.currentTime might actually be in the past by the time the audio thread sees it.  You might want to try context.currentTime + 0.01 or something.

Comment: Didn't know they were separate threads, thanks. Yes, examples I was looking at all have a little add audioCtx.currentTime + 0.01, sometimes more, and I try bigger numbers until I get a significant delay, and that doesn't seem to help. Just longer before you hear the gain change.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soundOfSilver/9aytLqfL/23/   I tried to put together all the relevant components in my code here, but am still fiddling. Right now I'm trying to get the sound file to play back in there at all.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use setValueAtTime - use setTargetAtTime, with a small value for timeConstant (like, try 0.01 as a starting point).  That will dezipper the setting.

Comment: That totally worked, thanks! What's your favorite resource out there for Web Audio API? So I don't have to ask you a ton of followup questions about the difference between those 2 functions?